# Нужно удалить элемент из SQLite, а затем из RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, sqlite, recyclerview

Как сделать так чтобы удались данные и из RecyclerView и из SQLite? Проблема в том, что в SQLite id autoincrement, а в RecyclerView он обновляется каждый раз при удаление из списка.

Comment: Так удаляете из базы данных

Comment: Потом удаляете из таблицы данных и обновляет таблицу

Comment: Как я понимаю, проблема в том, что RecyclerView нумерует элементы подряд всегда, а id в бд могут быть порублены на интервалы. Но в какой момент возниакет проблема неясно. Вы жекогда удаляете из бд элемент знаете его номер в листе, т.к. в него ткнули и в событии вы его получите, и знаете id элемента в бд, т.к. по номеру в листе вы легко найдете данные об объекте в этой ячейке и, соответственно, id. Либо распишите подробнее в чем проблема, либо останетесь с проблемой наедине

Answer (score 0):

Вы приложили слишком мало информации, чтоб помочь вам более точечно. Но я попробую вам помочь в общих чертах.

База данных и RecyclerView это две совершенно разные вещи. У них абсолютно две разные ответственности, а это означает, что они не должны знать друг о друге ничего. И работа одной никак не должна зависеть от другой.

Исходя из того, что у вас есть такая ошибка смею предположить, что ваш RecyclerView нарушает этот контракт и создаёт вас проблемы.

Каково должно быть взаимодействие между этими двумя сущностями?

- Есть база данных, все что она знает это только и только то как сохранить то что ей передали на вход.
- Есть RecyclerView, вся ответственность которого это отобразить список переданный ему извне. Он не должен сам ходить в базу данных. Он должен быть максимально тупым. Просто отобразить данные которые ему передаются на вход через метод вроде такого:

  public void update(List items) {
      this.items = items;
      notifyDataSetChanged ();
  }
- Получать и подготавливать ваши данные вы должны за пределами вашего RecyclerView и просто передавать новые данные в адаптер в метод `update()`.

Хорошо бы даже чтоб сама View (Activity, Fragment) ничего не знала о базе данных. Но это выходит за рамки ответа. Но я советую вам прочесть про паттерны MVP, MVVM.